# How to add column header on txt files using read.delim?

Tags: r, header

I have a business analytics subject this sem and we were given some exercises to do using the `read.delim()` function in r.

I've tried inputting a code to import and add column headers to a txt file (that has no headers) but the headers were misaligned with the df. This is the code that I've tried:

I've asked my classmates for help but they typed the same code and the headers were aligned properly. I don't know that I did wrong.
this is what the headers look like with the dataset

[image]

Comment: how is your data delimited within txt file? tabular? comma? semicolon? any other?
You can specify delimiter when importing data with *sep =* within read.delim function. 

Please do atleast minimal research before posting a question. This is 5 seconds googling :)

Comment: Try: `hotdogs <- read.table("hotdogs.txt",sep="",header=FALSE, col.names = c("type", "calories", "sodium"))`